# Can the keyword `this` be used in the class scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

It seems that I can define lambda expressions that capture `this` in the class scope. As far as I read N4640 up to date working draft, I couldn't find the sentence that allows the behavior. I think that I'm missing something...

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
    std::function<void()> f1 = [this]{ ++i; };
    int i = 0;
};

int main() {
    foo a;
    foo const& cref = a;
    cref.f1();
    std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
}
```

Running demo. (g++ -std=c++11 pedantic)
https://wandbox.org/permlink/HPzaOxbBkOQOmuS6

**Updated**

Thanks to @Brian and @cpplerner comments, I understand what my essential question is. That is "Is the keyword `this` allowed to use in the class scope? not only non-static member function scope."
If it does, I can use `this` in the lambda expression capture list in the class scope. It's very clear.

It seems that `this` in the class scope regard as non-const pointer.

In order to solve my essential question, I read N4640 9.2.2.1 The this pointer [class.this]. It seems that it is allowed syntactically, but I couldn't find the semantic description. For non-static member functions, I found the semantic description at 9.2.2/3 and 9.2.2/4.

**updated**

I updated the title of the question to represent my essential question.

The original question title was **Can lambda expression in the class scope capture this?**

Comment: Is there any reason why you think it *shouldn't* be allowed?

Comment: @Brian, I thought that `this` can be allowed only in non-static member functions. But it seems that I am wrong. I wrote another example. https://wandbox.org/permlink/CUiG2KIOgD6q9qFy

Comment: ["A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope is a local lambda expression; any other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-default or simple-capture in its lambda-introducer. "](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#3) :/

Comment: You are looking for [\[expr.prim.this\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.this). @cpplearner That is [core issue 1632](https://wg21.link/CWG1632).

Comment: @T.C.thank you for point the information. That is exactly I'm looking for!!

Comment: @cpplearner, I noticed that I misunderstood your comment at first. But now, I believe that I understand correctly, and I reflect it my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Motivation to answer (by myself)

Thanks to the comments, my question is solved. I summarize the answer of the question using the comments for other people that see the question.

### Can the keyword `this` be used in the class scope?

Yes. According to [[expr.prim.this]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this),

"The keyword this names a pointer to the object for which a non-static member function is invoked or **a non-static data member's initializer** ([class.mem]) is evaluated."

See [@T.C 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649241/can-the-keyword-this-be-used-in-the-class-scope#comment74350768_43649241).

### Can the keyword `this` be written in the capture list of the lambda expression in the class scope?

No.

At least in the current draft of the C++ standard [n4618](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf), but C++ standard committee recognized as [issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1632).

Here is the reason why `this` is NOT permitted.

According to [expr.prim.lambda](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-3),

"A *lambda-expression* whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope is a *local lambda expression; any other *lambda-expression* shall not have a *capture-default* or *simple-capture* in its *lambda-introducer*."

A *lambda-expression* in the class scope is NOT a *local lambda expression*. Because a [class scope](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class) is not a [block scope](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.block). Here is a definition of the word [block](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block#nt:compound-statement).

So the *lambda-expression* in the class scple shall not have *capture-default* or *simple-capture* in its *lambda-introducer*.

The keyword `this` is one of *simple-capture*. See [expr.prim.lambda.capture](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#nt:simple-capture).

Hence, a *lambda-expression* that is in the class scope cannot capture `this`.

See this [@cpplearner 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649241/can-the-keyword-this-be-used-in-the-class-scope#comment74346709_43649241) and [@T.C 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649241/can-the-keyword-this-be-used-in-the-class-scope#comment74350768_43649241).

### Compiler implementation

I tested the following code on g++ and clang++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
    std::function<void()> lambda_in_class_scope = [this]{
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    std::cout << &f << std::endl;
    f.lambda_in_class_scope();
}
```

Output:

```
0x7fff8f409cb0
0x7fff8f409cb0
```

I got the same address. This indicates that `this` is captured correctly.

Here are running demos:

g++ 6.3
https://wandbox.org/permlink/FdhxJhVvripOQ1ng

clang++ 4.0
https://wandbox.org/permlink/kGoNBIoV5WTZV0sy